# Is it possible to list all the files for which Tortoise SVN resolved conflicts automatically?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

When I merge two branches and conflicts occur, in many cases Tortoise SVN is able to resolve them automatically.

However, once I click on "Prefer repository" and all merge is completed, I would like to review the files for which the conflict occurred. Is it possible to list them or displayed detailed information about way of resolving conflicts for them (once the merge is completed)?

Comment: Did you try viewing the log and checking the `Include merged revisions` box at the bottom of that dialog?

Comment: @KenWhite - this is useless